# Boolean Expression simplification help

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, computer-algebra-systems

Hi I am new to the board.  Taking a computer architecture course and I am having trouble understanding further simplification on a question I got on a previous quiz.  When I type in the expression after setting up my K map and simplifying I come to this:

(A AND B) OR (NOT A AND NOT B).

Through the rules of simplification A+ NOT A=1.  Does this then mean that AB +A'B'=1? and if so how is that represented as a logic gate?

Thanks.

Comment: (AB)' = NOT A OR NOT B. Thus, AB + (A'B + AB' + A'B') = 1. Thus, you cannot say AB +A'B'=1 without knowing the values of A'B and AB'

Comment: Don't lose sight of what expressions mean! Informally what does the given one mean? "Either A and B are both true or they're both false". And *that* can't always take the value 'true" can it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  On the quiz I got the circuit right and had the expression AB+AB(with line over both) I assumed that expression is written in a long form like A AND B OR NOT AND AND NOT B.  Is that incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have the truth table of `AB + A'B'`.

```
A | B | AB + A'B'
--+---+--------------
0 | 0 | 0.0 + 1.1 = 1
0 | 1 | 0.1 + 1.0 = 0
```

The assertion that `AB + A'B' =1` is definitely not true. Now the source of confusion seems to be the following.

If `A + A' = 1` then should `AB + A'B'` is also equal to 1. NO. The complement of AB is `(AB)'` and not `A'B'`.

Use de-Morgan theorem on `(AB)'` and you get the following,

```
(AB)' = A' + B'
```

BOOLEAN GATES REPRESENTING (AB)'

```
         +----------+     +--------+
   A ----|          |     |        |
         |    &     |-----|  Inv   |---- (AB)'
   B ----|          |     |        |
         +----------+     +--------+
```

Comment: AHH I see now.  Thank yo.  tghat is exactly where I was getting confused so the inverse of AB is (AB)' not A'B'..

How would you then represent AB+(AB)' via logic gates? Does that then =1? No matter what the output would always be 1..

Comment: How would I have broken down NOT(NOT(A AND B OR NOT A) OR B)?

I applied Demorgans to the first NOT BAR and came with AB'' AND A''' AND B'.  I applied teh identity law and got AB AND A' AND B'.  Doesn't that translate to A AND B AND NOT A AND NOT B?

Comment: @chamburger Updated the answer. I drew the gates representing (AB)'.

Comment: Thank you, got it now.  wish I could give votes but I'm a newb

Answer (score 0):

A'B' would be.

```
A---o|---| 
     | & |----A'B'
B---o|---|
```

The truth tables for (AB)' is:

```
(AB)' 
FF=T, 
FT=T, 
TF=T, 
TT=F.
```

Where as the truth table for A'B' is

```
A'B'
FF=T, 
FT=F, 
TF=F, 
TT=F.
```